# Import Accuracy/General Accuracy

Tags: excel, input

```
r[i] = SetPrecision[
   Import[epath, {"Data", epath2, 9 + counts + 5*i - 2, excelfile2}], 
   prec];
```

epath is file name, epath2 is tab, count is row, excelfile2 is column. In the excel the cell holds the equation =.769/39.37. According to excel it .0195326390652781000000000. However in mathematica the result comes back as

```
r[1] = 0.01953263906527813106861480
```

Where is the extra 13106861480 coming from?

Whats more is if you put the equation into mathematica as .769/39.37 the result you get is 0.01953263906527813453806175 which has 3453806175. Where are these differences coming from? How come they don't change, I though it was computer noise but it's not changing. Can someone help?

Comment: What is `prec`?

Comment: precision of argument set, 200

Comment: When `SetPrecision` is used to raise the precision of a number, it augments with binary (as opposed to decimal) zeros. `In[163]:= n1 = .769/39.37;
n2 = SetPrecision[n1, 30]

Out[164]= 0.0195326390652781345380617494811

In[165]:= RealDigits[n2, 2]

Out[165]= {{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
  0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
   0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, -5}`

Comment: I don't understand? it just generates extra numbers? How are they not random then? and which one is accurate/correct?